# C++ perfect forwarding: how to avoid dangling references

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following problem: I have a number of classes, each implementing a `get()` function. The following `container1` and `container2` are examples of such classes:

```cpp
struct expensive_type {
    int v;
};

struct container1 {
    expensive_type get() const {
        return { 1 };
    }
};

struct container2 {
    expensive_type x;
    expensive_type& get() {
        return x;
    }
};
```

I want to create a wrapper, templated on `C` and `F`, that implements the same `get()` functionality of `C`, but applies a function to the result:

```cpp
template<typename C, typename F>
struct wrapper {
    F f;
    C c;
    decltype(auto) get() {
        return f(c.get());
    }
};
```

I would now like to create a function `f` for a trivial wrapper, that simply returns its argument unchanged. I thought this would work:

```cpp
auto f = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) {
    return forward<decltype(x)>(x);
};

wrapper<container1, decltype(f)> trivial_wrapper1 { f, {} };
wrapper<container2, decltype(f)> trivial_wrapper2 { f, {} };
```

, but unfortunately `trivial_wrapper1.get()` returns `expensive_type{0}` instead of `expensive_type{1}` (at least with the `-O2` flag). I guess the problem has something to do with dangling references, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

My question is: how to correctly implement the function `f` so that it it acts as a perfect identity, without ever copying its argument?

To clarify, here are examples of the intended behaviour:

```cpp
cout << trivial_wrapper1.get().v << endl; // should print 1, prints 0 as of now
trivial_wrapper2.get().v = 2;
cout << trivial_wrapper2.c.x.v << endl; // should print 2, and it does as of now
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue here is that there is no temporary extension through functions.  When you do

```
return f(c.get());
```

when `c` is a `container1` you return by value so you have temporary.  That temporary only lives to the end of the full expression which means it dies once the return statement finishes.  This is why you have a dangling reference.

This leaves you in a little bit of a bind though.  what `f` would need to do is return by value if it got a temporary but this could copy which could be expensive.  There really isn't a way around that though if you are going to pass the return value through an intermediary function.  That would give you an `f` like

```
auto f = [](auto&& x) -> std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(x)>,
                                            std::remove_reference_t<decltype(x)>, 
                                            decltype(x)> {
    return x;
};
```

which returns by value for rvalues and by reference for lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value gets transformed into an r-value reference. This is usually good when you forward *into* functions, but you're trying to forward *out* the return value.

Instead of `auto&&` type deduction, you'll need `decltype(auto)` deduction.

But indeed you used `decltype(auto)` as every place but the one you can't: the `auto&&` lambda parameter.

My solution would be to decay copy when `get()` return by value.

```
template<typename C, typename F>
struct wrapper {
    F f;
    C c;
    decltype(auto) get() {
        using get_t = decltype(c.get());
        using f_result_t = decltype(f(c.get()));

        if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<get_t>) {
            return f(c.get());
        } else {
            return std::decay_t<f_result_t>(f(c.get())); // decay copy
        }
    }
};
```

The solution is not obvious. What happens when you do this?

```
auto f = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) {
    static auto v = std::decay_t<decltype(x)>{};
    return (v); // return by ref
};

wrapper<container1, decltype(f)> trivial_wrapper1 { f, {} };
wrapper<container2, decltype(f)> trivial_wrapper2 { f, {} };
```

Now, even without the decay copy it will work as expected. If you use decay copy, you must write the intent of the function and how it's supposed to behave.